# Does polkit.Result.NO deny actions even to the root user?

Tags: polkit

E.g. in this example from the Arch Wiki, does `systemd-logind` still permit the `root` user to request suspend and hibernation?

> The following rule disables suspend and hibernate for all users.
>
> /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-disable-suspend.rules
>
> ```
> polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
>     if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend" ||
>         action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions" ||
>         action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate" ||
>         action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions")
>     {
>         return polkit.Result.NO;
>     }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Creating these rules succeeds in stopping the suspend keyboard button from working inside GNOME.

`sudo systemctl suspend -i` - i.e. requesting suspend as root - continues to work.

Strangely, `systemctl suspend -i` causes GNOME to prompt for an administrator password.  So polkit.Result.NO seems to mean the same as polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN.

Software versions:

- systemd-239-12.git8bca462.fc29.x86_64
- polkit-0.115-4.4.fc29.x86_64
- gnome-shell-3.30.2-1.fc29.x86_64